# JBoss transation timeout limit

Tags: jboss, transactions, jta

Is there a limit in the JBoss transactionTimeout value?

I do have a long running transaction, and even I put 7200 in the JBoss transactionTimeout value, it is becaming inactive after more or less 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

you need check multiple parameter apart from setting the value.

Following are some of them.

1. Driver Level(If the datasource parameter `set-tx-query-timeout` is true then `query-timeout` applied).
2. Network Firewall timeout policy
3. TransactionTimeout set on the `javax.transaction.xa.XAResource`

Comment: Thank you Arunkumar, I will make a try.